# sqoop import fails due to classnotfoundexception

Tags: sqoop

i am trying to import data from SQL server using sqoop.
then sqoop job fails with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : Class   not found

i have checked in the /tmp directory, under sqoop- i could see the .jar file along with .class and .java file..

what could be the cause of ClassNotFound exception, below is the complete error

```
15/11/11 11:25:18 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
15/11/11 11:25:18 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local194018022_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class device not found

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class device not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getInputClass(DBConfiguration.java:403)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat.createDBRecordReader(DataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:237)
```

Regards
Hari

Comment: The "device" is the name of the table getting imported

Comment: Please post the command you use to invoke sqoop.

Comment: Chris.. below is the command

Comment: sqoop import --driver "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://<databaseNameLPort>;databaseName=<dbName>" --username <username> --password <password> --split-by device_id --table device --target-dir /user/hduser/device

Comment: I don't use --driver.  Try without specifying that argument.  The connection string should provide enough information.

Comment: tried without --driver, it is running but exiting with same error.. classnotfoundexception.. i think the /tmp where the .jar gets loaded is not available for the runtime.. but i have not seen anywhere mentioning about /tmp being in classpath

Comment: i have used the --bindir and --class-name by providing the generated jar as well and still the issue is same, ClassNotFoundException: Class device not found

Comment: are you sure the database user has access to the table 'device'?

Comment: i did a workaround by binding to the local directory where i am executing the sqoop command, so it creates the jar file into the local directory and executes fine.. if i don't give the bindir then the above error occurs.. so far i have moved on from this.. but definitely need to find out the reason of this behavior

Answer (score 3):

I have faced same problem but now got solution, i have observed your error log.your hadoop is in local mode as it clearly shows that it running localjobrunner, just try to check your hadoop mode if its in pseudo distributed mode then fine, if it is in local mode then make it pseudo, distributed mode

with following steps:

```
**Pseudo-Distributed Operation**

Hadoop can also be run on a single-node in a pseudo-distributed mode where each Hadoop daemon runs in a separate Java process.
Configure parameters as follows:

**1.etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml:**
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.admin.user.env</name>
        <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
        <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

**2. etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml**
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

**3. Start ResourceManager daemon and NodeManager daemon:**
  $ sbin/start-yarn.sh
```

now run your import command...

ex.

```
balasaheb@balasaheb:~$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqooptest --username root --table emppk --split-by id
```

Regards
Balasaheb

Comment: I met the same problem and this answer helps me!

Comment: Your code has helped me in problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

use '--bindir' option, make query code compiled to the same place

Comment: This reply is a bit brief but it solved my issue. Just add `--binddir /pathtosqoop/lib` to the sqoop import command

Comment: I assume there is a environment variable that can be set to fix this issue also